# Covariant return type best practices

Tags: java, generics, collections, covariance

I vaguely remember learning in university that the return type of a method should always be as narrow as possible, but my search for any references online came up empty and SonarQube calls it a code smell. E.g. in the following example (note that `TreeSet` and `Set` are just examples)

```
public interface NumberGetter {
    Number get();

    Set<Number> getAll();
}

public class IntegerGetter implements NumberGetter {

    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public TreeSet<Number> getAll() {
        return new TreeSet<>(Collections.singleton(1));
    }
}
```

SonarQube tells me

> Declarations should use Java collection interfaces such as "List" rather than specific implementation classes such as "LinkedList". The purpose of the Java Collections API is to provide a well defined hierarchy of interfaces in order to hide implementation details. (squid:S1319)

I see the point about hiding implementation details, since I cannot easily change the return type of IntegerGetter::getAll() without breaking backwards-compatibility. But by doing this, I also provide the consumers with potentially valuable information, i.e. they could change their algorithm to be more appropriate for using a `TreeSet`. And if they don't care about this property, they can still just use `IntegerGetter` (however they obtained it), like this:

```
Set<Number> allNumbers = integerGetter.getAll();
```

So I have the following questions:

- Is it appropriate for IntegerGetter::get() to return a narrower type?
- Is it appropriate for IntegerGetter::getAll() to return a narrower type?
- Are there any best practices regarding this topic or is the answer just "it depends"?

(N.B. SonarQube doesn't complain if I replace `TreeSet` with e.g. `SortedSet`. Is this code smell only about not using a Collection API interface? What if there is only a concrete class for my particular problem?)

Comment: If they want to use a specialized algorithm, they can use `instanceof`.  In general, SonarQube is recommending the correct best practice: always use an appropriate collection interface whenever possible.

Comment: It's really a judgment call. There's an argument that you should code to an interface, so returning a Set means you can make changes later and are not sort of screwed. On the other hand, if you're using the getter and need to continue to work with a TreeSet, then that's really part of your interface. If you're only doing Set methods after calling the getter, then it's safe to return Set. You can always make it more specific if you have a reason to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type must strike a balance between the needs of the caller and the needs of the implementation: the more you tell a caller about the return type, the harder it is to change that type later.

Which is more important will depend on the specific circumstances. Do you ever see this type changing? How valuable is knowing the type for the caller?

In the case of `IntegerGetter.get()`, it would be very surprising if the return type ever changes, so telling the caller does no harm.

In the case of `IntegerGetter.getAll()`, it depends on what the caller uses the method for:

- If he merely wants to iterate, an `Iterable` would be the right choice.
- If we need more methods such as size, `Collection` might.
- If he relies on the numbers being unique, a `Set`.
- If he additionally relies on the numbers being sorted, a `SortedSet`.
- And if it actually needs to be the red black tree from the JDK so it can manipulate its internal state directly for an ugly hack, a `TreeSet` might be the right choice.

Comment: [`NavigableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/NavigableSet.html)…

Answer (score 1):

I try - as a rule of thumb - to use on method signature the most general *type* (class or interface does'n matter) that supports the API I need: more general the *type*, more minimal the API.
So, if I need a parameter representing a *family* of object of the same type, I start using `Collection`; if in the specific scenario is the idea of *ordering* important, I use `List`, avoiding to publish any info about the specific `List` implementation I use internally: my idea is to keep the ability to change implementation (may be for performance optimization, to support a different data structore, and so on) without break clients.

As you stated, publishing information like *I use a `TreSet`* can leave place for client-side optimization - but my idea is that **it depends**: case by case you can evaluate if the specific scenario requires to relax the general rule to *expose the more general interface you can*.

So, coming to your questions:

1. yes, it is appropriate in the `IntegerGetter` implementation of `NumberGetter` interface to return a narrower type: Java allows you to do and you are not breaking my *more generic is more beautiful* rule: the `NumberGetter` interface exposes the more general interface using `Number` as return type but in specific implementations we can use a narrower return type to guide the method implementation: clients referring to the more abstract interface are not affected by this choice and client referring to the specific subclass can try advantage from using the more concrete interface
2. the same as the previous point, but I think it's less useful than in the previous case for clients: may be a client can find useful to refer to `Integer` than to `Number` (if I use explicitly a `NumberGetter`, may be I think in terms of `Integer`s, not in term of `Number`s), but referring to `TreeSet` rather than to `Set` is useful only if you need the API exposed by the subclass and not by the interface...
3. see initial dissertation

It's a quasi-philosophic question - and so is my answer: I hope it can be useful to you!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot have a single answer, as it depends on the usecase.
And by that I mean that it depends on the degree of flexibility you want your implementation to have, plus the degree of flexibility you want to give the consumers of your `API`.

I'll give you a more general answer.

Do you want your consumer to loop-only? Return a `Collection<T>`.
Do you want your consumer to be able to access by index? Return a `List<T>`
Do you want your consumer to know and be able to efficiently verify if an element is present? Return a `Set<T>`
And so on.

The same approach is valid for input parameters. What's the point of accepting a `List<T>`, or even concrete classes such as `ArrayList<T>` or `LinkedList<T>`, if you only loop it? You are just giving your code less flexibility for future modifications.

What you're doing here with the `IntegerGetter`'s inherited methods' return types is called *type specialization*. It's okay as long as you keep exposing *interfaces* to the outer world.

My rule of thumb is being as generic as possibile when dealing with the outer world, and being as specific as possible when implementing critical (core) parts of my application, to restrict the possible use-cases, protect myself from abusing what I just coded, and for documentation purposes.

What you **shouldn't** absolutely be doing is using `instanceof` or `class` comparison to discover the actual type and take different routes. That's ruining a codebase.